# FFmpeg: Is there a hardware scaling filter available for macOS, like an equivalent of scale_cuda or scale_qsv?

Tags: ffmpeg

on macOS, I'd like to be able to scale videos using the GPU since it's a lot faster than on the CPU.

Comment: Execute `ffmpeg -hwaccels` for getting a list of hardware acceleration methods.

Comment: I did and it said, Hardware acceleration methods: videotoolbox. That's the only one. It doesn't seem like there is hardware scaling, does it?

Comment: I don't have a system with macOS for testing. You may try updating FFmpeg version to the latest stable release.